# How to solve unused argument error as part of a meltAssay?

Tags: r

When using meltAssay to convert a SummarizedExperiment object, the central data infrastructure for microbiome analysis in Bioconductor, into long data.frame, I use the following lines according to the instructions in the book:

```
tse <- transformSamples(tse, method="relabundance")

molten_tse <- meltAssay(tse,
                        add_row_data = TRUE,
                        add_col_data = TRUE,
                        assay_name = "relabundance")
molten_tse
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in .melt_assay(x, abund_values, feature_name, sample_name, ...)
> :    unused argument (assay_name = "relabundance")

Comment: Can you say exactly what Bioconductor package you are using and what version of that package? It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax instead: (abund_values instead of assay_names.
There seems to be an error in the book)

```
molten_tse <- meltAssay(tse,
                        add_row_data = TRUE,
                        add_col_data = TRUE,
                        abund_values  = "relabundance")
```